# String variable as import module specifier

Tags: python, import, importerror

I have tried the following:

```
>> modname = 'sys'
>> import modname
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named modname
```

Why does import not recognize 'sys' as the name of the module to be imported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `importlib` module if you want to import a module based on a string.

```
>>> import importlib
>>> mod = importlib.import_module('sys')
>>> mod
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a workaround (hence the upvote), but it does not quite answer my question, or does it not?

Comment: @MarcosGonzalez You can't do it with a string

Comment: @MarcosGonzalez `import` statement doesn't works with strings.

Comment: Why? It seems so 'intuitive' ;-)

Comment: @MarcosGonzalez *There should be one way to do it*

Comment: @MarcosGonzalez May be some other languages support such feature , but python's `import` statement doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> modname = 'sys'
>>> sys = __import__(modname)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a workaround (hence the upvote), but it does not quite answer my question, or does it not?

Comment: @MarcosGonzalez I suggesst you accept the answer by AshwiniChaudhary It is the current accepted way to do it

Comment: @MarcosGonzalez I wasn't aware of `importlib` when posting this ;)