# Use string to specify `from my_package import my_class as my_custom_name`

Tags: python, python-import, dynamic-import

I'd like to make the following line dynamic :

```
from my_package import my_class as my_custom_name
```

I know how to dynamically import modules via string

```
import importlib
module_name = "my_package"
my_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914944/string-variable-as-import-module-specifier). However it still doesn't let me specify the class I want to import (`my_class`) and the alias I want to assign to the class name (`my_custom_name`). I'm using python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps. Number one, you can reference a module directly using `importlib`:

```
importlib.import_module('my_package.my_module') # You can use '.'.join((my_package, my_module))
```

Your class will be contained in the module itself as an attribute, as in any import. As such, just use

```
my_custom_name = importlib.import_module('my_package.my_module').__dict__['my_class']
```

or even better

```
my_custom_name  = getattr(importlib.import_module('my_package.my_module'), 'my_class')
```

Comment: You don't even need the `__dict__`, `import_module(...).my_class` or `getattr(import_module(...), my_class_name)` should do.

Comment: Thx. Third solution is most beautiful to read, though the ")" bracket is missing before 'my_class' ;).